# How to render native javascript in vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a library that is written in native javascript that I need to import into a vue component in order for it to render. I don't know what i'm doing wrong

```
import { RowSelection } from 'gridjs-selection'
import { h, Grid, Row } from 'gridjs'
import Switcher from '@/components/Switcher.vue'
import http from '@/http-common'

const grid = new Grid({
  columns: ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number'],
  data: [
    ['John', 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    ['Mark', 'mark@gmail.com', '(01) 22 888 4444']
  ]
}).render(document.getElementById('table'))

export default grid
```

My component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="table"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import gridJs from '@/components/integration/IntegrationsTableJs'
export default Vue.extend({})
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do what you try to do. `table` doesn't exist at the time when the script is evaluated. If it's your own script, do DOM-related operations inside a component.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the element before it is rendered. Your custom script is executed as its imported, but before the elements are rendered in the page. You can make use of Vue's life-cycle hooks.

But before that, you need to make a small change in your custom script so that it can be called as and when required. Basically you need to wrap your custom logic in a method.

```
import { RowSelection } from 'gridjs-selection'
import { h, Grid, Row } from 'gridjs'
import Switcher from '@/components/Switcher.vue'
import http from '@/http-common'

const grid = () => { new Grid({
  columns: ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number'],
  data: [
    ['John', 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    ['Mark', 'mark@gmail.com', '(01) 22 888 4444']
  ]
}).render(document.getElementById('table')) }

export default grid
```

Read more about exporting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Now in your Vue component, you can call this method inside the `mounted` hook. Read about Vue life-cycle hooks [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="table"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import gridJs from '@/components/integration/IntegrationsTableJs'
export default Vue.extend({
    // life-cycle hook.
    mounted: function() {
        gridJs();
        // if you want sexy code; try passing the reference to the "table" element as a parameter from here. 
    }
})
</script>
```